# Filter JSON returned from GitHub API via Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the latest release information from a github repository and grab a specific asset in that release. The following code prints out the release tag and the all the assets under the Asset structure. I'd like to be able to pull out a specific item and its download url, such as just the ajour.exe tag. Can I do that via the struct, or should I be parsing the output to grab it?

```
func GetGithubAsset() {
    testUri := "https://api.github.com/repos/ajour/ajour/releases/latest"
    type githubApiData struct {
       AppVersion string `json:"tag_name"`
       Assets     []struct {
          Name               string `json:"name"`
          BrowserDownloadURL string `json:"browser_download_url"`
       }
    }
    resp, err := http.Get(testUri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var data githubApiData
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(jsonErr)
    }
    fmt.Println(data.AppVersion)
    fmt.Println(data.Assets)
}
```

Comment: I fixed a couple of typos in the code that caused it not to compile. One other thing to note is that `ioutil` is deprecated for new code and it's better now to call `io.ReadAll`. You should also add a `defer resp.Body.Close()` after the `http.Get` error checking (see example at the top of https://pkg.go.dev/net/http).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Note that the `json.Unmarshal` does parse the output for you. All you need to is loop through the `Assets` field, something like so (in place of `fmt.Println(data.Assets)`):

```golang
    for _, asset := range data.Assets {
        if asset.Name == "ajour.exe" {
            fmt.Println(asset.BrowserDownloadURL)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The json tag `json:"assets"` is missing

```golang
func GetGithubAsset() {
    testUri := "https://api.github.com/repos/ajour/ajour/releases/latest"
    type githubApiData struct {
        AppVersion string `json:"tag_name"`
        Assets     []struct {
            Name               string `json:"name"`
            BrowserDownloadURL string `json:"browser_download_url"`
        } `json:"assets"`
    }
    resp, err := http.Get(testUri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var data githubApiData
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(jsonErr)
    }
    fmt.Println(data.AppVersion)
    fmt.Println(data.Assets)
}
```

Comment: For reference, it's probably better for something like this to be a comment, as it's good feedback but doesn't answer the question at hand. Note that in this case `json:"assets"` isn't strictly necessary as the field name is the same (and `Unmarshal` ignores case for this), though it still might be good to be explicit.